# Simple Harmonic Motion definition with proof

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, definition, spring

I'm currently Grade 11 and learning physics with the topic of oscillations, sadly my teacher didn't really give me a good understanding, besides a formula we have to memorize and just use mindlessly. My book sadly states that the formula derived is above the "standard of mathematics for my level". However I'm quite an enthusiast on Physics and Mathematics and I think I may understand. I tried to check other sources, but they just give me an explanation that relies on circular reasoning, or maybe I'm wrong not sure? Anyways, here is my question

My book states that simple harmonic motion is defined as the motion of a particle about a fixed point such that it's acceleration is proportional to it's displacement from the fixed point, and is in the opposite direction.

Then suddenly I'm given this formula $$a = -\omega^2x,$$ where $\omega^2$ is a constant and $x$ is the displacement. I would understand this formula, if it weren't for this angular frequency $\omega$, suddenly the book mentions that this $\omega$ is angular frequency. My question is why? and how? From what they tell me this is only supposed to be a constant (negative one), i understand why they made it squared and the negative, however what I don't understand is how is there suddenly angular frequency, shouldn't it be
$$a = -k^2x,$$ where $-k^2$ is a negative constant. Please show me a reasoning in a way that feels "discovering" if possible, if not than that's okay, as long as the proof is valid.

Comment: To see the connection between angular frequency and the negative constant, you might try reading [this section of an OpenStax textbook](https://openstax.org/books/college-physics-2e/pages/16-6-uniform-circular-motion-and-simple-harmonic-motion).  You're right that it's not immediately obvious that this constant should have anything to do with rotations, but the above link shows how it's connected.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are in grade 11, I assume you already know
the [sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine) function and a little bit of differential calculus
(especially how to calculate the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of a function).
Using these tools it is not hard to clarify your questions,

One way to define a simple harmonic motion is by saying it is
a displacement $x(t)$ which depends on time $t$ by the sine function:
$$x(t)=C\sin(\omega t+\phi_0) \tag{1}$$
where $C$ (the maximum $x$ displacement) and $\phi_0$ (the
initial phase) are some constants, and
$\omega$ is another constant (called angular frequency).
The argument of the sine function (here $\omega t+\phi_0$) is always an
angle. Therefore it makes sense to call $\omega$ the angular velocity.
From this displacement $x(t)$ you can calculate the velocity $v(t)$
as the derivative of $x(t)$ with respect to $t$.
$$v(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\omega C\cos(\omega t+\phi_0) \tag{2}$$

And from this velocity $v(t)$ you can calculate the acceleration $a(t)$
as the derivative of $v(t)$ with respect to $t$.
$$a(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=-\omega^2 C\sin(\omega t+\phi_0) \tag{3}$$

When you now compare equations (1) and (3) then you see
$$a(t)=-\omega^2 x(t) \tag{4}$$
which is exactly the equation your teacher has given to you.

So from (1) you have proven (4).
You can also do it the other way round, i.e. from (4) you can prove (1).
Actually (1) and (4), although looking very different,
are two equivalent ways to define the [simple harmonic motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion).

Comment: Thanks, this was actually quite a great proof, and something I could follow on
10/10